# Cannot build with TeamCity and one git submodule

Tags: git, teamcity

I'm trying to get a build going on `TeamCity 6.5.6` with a `git` repo with one submodule but getting "failed to start build."

`.gitmodules` file:

```
[submodule "src/shared-contracts"]
path = src/shared-contracts
url = gitolite@myserver:shared-contracts
```

Stacktrace:

`Failed to start build: Server was not able to build correct patch, most likely due to VCS errors, will try again.
jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.patch.PatchDownloaderImpl$1: Server was not able to build correct patch, most likely due to VCS errors, will try again.`

`Caused by: jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.patches.UnsuccessfulPatchException: Failed to build patch for build #s5 {build id=19947}, VCS root: gitolite@myserver:myrepo#mapi-qa {instance id=1152, parent id=280}, due to error: Patch building failed: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.CorruptObjectException: Repository 'gitolite@myserver:myrepo' has submodule in commit 'c8f8416d86e3ed274302ff2f316792a37f041322' at path 'src/shared-contracts', but has no entry for this path in .gitmodules configuration.`

I did a fresh clone locally, checked out the branch from the TC config and `git submodule update --init` checked out the submodule correctly to src/shared-contracts.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, did you check `.gitmodules`?

Comment: Locally yes, as above, assumed would be same on server, will confirm ...

Comment: I'd try it with newer version of TeamCity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I updated to `TeamCity` 7.1.3 and the problem continued to occur.

I removed the submodule following the answer [How do I remove a submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-git-submodule)

I then re-added it, but this time with URL set to

`url = gitolite@myserver:shared-contracts.git`

instead of

`url = gitolite@myserver:shared-contracts` and the issue was resolved.

Comment: I had the same problem and I removed the submodule and added it back with an https address instead of the ssh and it worked.